# Free skew fields over sets of different cardinal

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, division-algebras

Let $K$ be a field and let $X$ be a set. Denote by $\mathcal D_K(X)$ the free skew $K$-field on $X$.

> Assume that $|X|\ne |Y|$. Is it true that $\mathcal D_K(X)$ and 
>   $\mathcal D_K(Y)$ are not isomorphic?

There are several constructions of $\mathcal D_K(X)$. The standard one is the following. Let $F_X$ be a free group on $X$. Fix a bi-invariant total order $\le$ on $F_X$ and let $K_{\le}(\!(F_X)\!)$ be the Malcev-Neumann ring of formal series (it consists of formal series having well-ordered support). One proves that $K_{\le}(\!(F_X)\!)$ is a skew field. Then $\mathcal D_K(X)$ is isomorphic to the division closure of the group algebra $K[F_X]$ in  $K_{\le}(\!(F_X)\!)$.

Comment: Schofield proved that any generating set (as a skew field over $K$) of size $n$ of the free skew field on $n$ generators is a free generating set, which answers the question when at least one of $X$ and $Y$ is finite, at least if by “isomorphic” you mean as $K$-algebras.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, you are right. For finite $X$,  it is Theorem 10.11 in Schofield's book. I had a feeling that I had seen it before. Thank you!